# Changing colors of a group of shapes without selecting (fill & text)

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

With regard to the following code:

```
Sub Macro1 ()
   With ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("MyShapeGroup")) 
     .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = cPurp  ''cPurp is global constant
     .TextFrame.Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 2
   End With
End Sub
```

I can execute the macro with only the change to the fill color, however, when I add in the text color change I get an Application-defined or object-defined error.

So I tried this:

```
Sub Macro1()
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("MyShapeGroup")).ShapeRange
       .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = cPurp
       .TextFrame.Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 2
    End With
End Sub
```

Which throws an 'Object doesn't support this property or method' on the `With` line.

Also tried this:

```
Sub Macro1()
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("MyShapeGroup"))
       .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = cPurp
       .ShapeRange.TextFrame.Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 2
    End With
End Sub
```

Which throws another 'Object doesn't support this property or method' on the `.ShapeRange` line.

Also tried this:

```
Sub Macro1 ()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("MyShapeGroup")).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = cPurp ''cPurp is global constant
        .TextFrame.Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 2
    End With
End Sub
```

How can I efficiently do both the fill color change and the text color change without using a select?

---

Updated with working method (tested in and Excel 2010 & Excel in Office365):

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
        With ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("MyShapeGroup"))
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
            .TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 255)
        End With
End Sub
```

Comment: How did you create "MyShapeGroup"?

Comment: Since you are in a Macro why not loop through the Array of shapes and set  properties 1x1???

Comment: @Raystafarian it is the name of the group of shapes changed from whatever the default was, probably Group 1

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `TextFrame2.TextRange` property instead:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim shp As Shape
        For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("MyShapeGroup"))
            shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
            shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 255)
        Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think your code is actually looping through each shape in the group, hence why `TextFrame` won't work.  It's looping through once where `shp` is the whole group and changing the colors of all shapes at once.  To loop the array needs to be set up as `(Array("Shape 1", "Shape 2"))` etc.  When looping through individual shapes then TextFrame or TextFrame2 will work.

Comment: Another way that makes the above work: `For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("MyShapeGroup")).GroupItems`

Comment: Hm, yeah that makes sense. I didn't really test that part of it.

Answer (score 1):

I am no good at VBA, but I think this worked for me!

```
Sub test()
    Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes("MyShapeGroup").GroupItems
        shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        shp.TextFrame.Characters.Font.Color = vbWhite
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: See my comment below the other answer.  This works, but it's not actually looping through anything, so it's not a very good answer.